# How to specify ssoSettingsApi feature flag when running Grafana in a container on Azure

Tags: grafana

I'm running the latest Grafana v. 10.4.0 on an Azure Web app in a docker container.   I am wanting to enable one of the feature flags named ssoSettingsApi.   I tried setting an Environment Variable of ssoSettingsApi to "true" but it seems that the there is some name change as any Environment variables I see set are in the format of GF_SOMETHING_OR_OTHER .   how do you set ssoSettingsApi.

Answer (score 0):

grafana.ini

> [feature_toggles]
>
> ssoSettingsApi = true

helm-chart

> ```
> grafana.ini:
>   feature_toggles:
>     ssoSettingsApi: true
> ```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).